# Setting up Azure SQL data sync's sync group

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-sync

I just tried setting up Azure SQL data sync's sync group using sample Azure SQL database. I am syncing dbo.BuildVersion table of the sample database.

I get the following error on member database.

> Database provisioning failed with the exception "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.Inner exception: SqlException ID: 39f49622-6a56-4a44-8e55-2a646f99a584, Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:156, Message: SQL error with code 156 For more information, provide tracing ID ‘679953bc-7dac-4490-89e9-ea6d145d0442’ to customer support."

How should I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried providing tracing ID ‘679953bc-7dac-4490-89e9-ea6d145d0442’ to customer support?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by creating empty table in the member database first and then running the sync.

Does Sync service not create table when table does not exist in the member database?

Answer (score 0):

It does create it, however, under certain circumstances it fails to create it do to some issue with the schema itself. Therefore, the workaround, as you figured out, is to create the table manually.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29934674)

Comment: How did my response not answer the question? He said, he was trying to use Azure Data Sync to on Azure SQL Database against the dbo.BuildVersion table and asked how to resolve that error he posted. He then posted a reply saying he is able to resolve the issue by creating an empty table in the member database and then running the sync. He asked whether the sync service creates the table if it doesn't already exist. My response was spot on. I said it does, however, under certain circumstances it fails so you have to do it manually.